# Chrome developer tool CSS position negative value

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I am learning CSS and using Chrome dev tool to check the size and position of a div element.

But the value on the right side of the "position box" for the div is negative. I don't know where it comes from.

What does this value mean? How can I find out what is causing this negative value?

The -0.8 in the picture is the value I am asking for.

[image]

This div has some children, and partial style for the div is like this:

```
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;

 width: 100%;
 height: 67.2px;

 padding-left: 2em;
 padding-right: 2em;
```

In the console, with the div selected, if I do

```
$0.getBoundingClientRect()
```

it will give following details:

```
DOMRect {x: 0, y: 0, width: 376, height: 67.20000457763672, top: 0, …}
bottom: 67.20000457763672
height: 67.20000457763672
left: 0
right: 376
top: 0
width: 376
x: 0
y: 0
```

Comment: Check the **Inspector > Rules** tab in the browser tools, you'll see all CSS that applies to the element there. You can also flip each css rule on/off there to see its effect, so it won't be hard to find the one that causes what you're seeing.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a sandbox snippet that will recreate your current problem? Codepen, codesandbox,  or whichever online sandbox you prefer.

Comment: can you edit your question with a jsffidle? because in my pc works fine (i only copy-pasted you CSS) https://imgur.com/a/wiURGNd

Comment: It could be related to the parent element. You used `width: 100%; position: fixed;`  but don't show css of parents elements. It could be inherit css... you need to show more information

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your comments. @BlackStar1991 's comment gave me some hint, it is caused by the other child from the same parent div. After removing that child, the negative value becomes 0.